# Is the HTM cortical learning algorithm defined by Numenta's paper restricted by Euclidean geometry?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, nupic, hierarchical-temporal-memory

Specifically, their most recent implementation.

http://www.numenta.com/htm-overview/htm-algorithms.php

Essentially, I'm asking whether non-euclidean relationships, or relationships in patterns that exceed the dimensionality of the inputs, can be effectively inferred by the algorithm in its present state?

HTM uses Euclidean geometry to determine "neighborship" when analyzing patterns. Consistently framed input causes the algorithm to exhibit predictive behavior, and sequence length is practically unlimited. This algorithm learns very well - but I'm wondering whether it has the capacity to infer nonlinear attributes from its input data.

For example, if you input the entire set of texts from Project Gutenberg, it's going to pick up on the set of probabilistic rules that comprise English spelling, grammar, and readily apparent features from the subject matter, such as gender associations with words, and so forth. These are first level "linear" relations, and can be easily defined with probabilities in a logical network.

A nonlinear relation would be an association of assumptions and implications, such as "Time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a banana." If correctly framed, the ambiguity of the sentence causes a predictive interpretation of the sentence to generate many possible meanings.

If the algorithm is capable of "understanding" nonlinear relations, then it would be able to process the first phrase and correctly identify that "Time flies" is talking about time doing something, and "fruit flies" are a type of bug.

The answer to the question is probably a simple one to find, but I can't decide either way. Does mapping down the input into a uniform, 2d, Euclidean plane preclude the association of nonlinear attributes of the data?

If it doesn't prevent nonlinear associations, my assumption would then be that you could simply vary the resolution, repetition, and other input attributes to automate the discovery of nonlinear relations - in effect, adding a "think harder" process to the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of HTM's, the structure of layers and columns mimics the structure of the neocortex. See appendix B here: http://www.numenta.com/htm-overview/education/HTM_CorticalLearningAlgorithms.pdf

So the short answer would be that since the brain can understand non-linear phenomenon with this structure, so can an HTM.

Initial, instantaneous sensory input is indeed mapped to 2D regions within an HTM. This does not limit HTM's to dealing with 2D representations any more than a one dimensional string of bits is limited to representing only one dimensional things. It's just a way of encoding stuff so that sparse distributed representations can be formed and their efficiencies can be taken advantage of.

To answer your question about Project Gutenberg, I don't think an HTM will really understand language without first understanding the physical world on which language is based and creates symbols for. That said, this is a very interesting sequence for an HTM, since predictions are only made in one direction, and in a way the understanding of what's happening to the fruit goes backwards. i.e. I see the pattern 'flies like a' and assume the phrase applies to the fruit the same way it did to time. HTM's do group subsequent input (words in this case) together at higher levels, so if you used Fuzzy Grouping (perhaps) as Davide Maltoni has shown to be effective, the two halves of the sentence could be grouped together into the same high level representation and feedback could be sent down linking the two specific sentences. Numenta, to my knowledge has not done too much with feedback messages yet, but it's definitely part of the theory.

Comment: Actually, I think one interesting thing about the directionality of an HTM is that you can turn it back on itself - create another region that takes mapped sequences and correlates them with the original data, and so on, until you get feedback loops going on at each level, that stabilize in auto-correlated nodes. Basically, you're defining each node as a member of a logical triple, creating a complex semantic graph.

Answer (score 1):

The software which runs the HTM is called NuPIC (Numenta Platform for Intelligent Computing). A NuPIC region (representing a region of neocortex) can be configured to either use topology or not, depending on the type of data it's receiving.

If you use topology, the usual setup maps each column to a set of inputs which is centred on the corresponding position in the input space (the connections will be selected randomly according to a probability distribution which favours the centre). The spatial pattern recognising component of NuPIC, known as the Spatial Pooler (SP), will then learn to recognise and represent localised topological features in the data.

There is absolutely no restriction on the "linearity" of the input data which NuPIC can learn. NuPIC can learn sequences of spatial patterns in extremely high-dimensional spaces, and is limited only by the presence (or lack of) spatial and temporal structure in the data.

To answer the specific part of your question, yes, NuPIC can learn non-Euclidean and non-linear relationships, because NuPIC is not, and cannot be modelled by, a linear system. On the other hand, it seems logically impossible to infer relationships of a dimensionality which exceeds that of the data.

The best place to find out about HTM and NuPIC, its Open Source implementation, is at NuPIC's [community website](http://numenta.org) (and mailing list).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It can do non-linear. Basically it is multilayer. And all multilayer neural networks can infer non linear relationships. And I think the neighborship is calculated locally. If it is calcualted locally then globally it can be piece wise non linear for example look at Local Linear Embedding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes HTM uses euclidean geometry to connect synapses, but this is only because it is mimicking a biological system that sends out dendrites and creates connections to other nearby cells that have strong activation at that point in time.

The Cortical Learning Algorithm (CLA) is very good at predicting sequences, so it would be good at determining "Time flies like an arrow, fruit flies like a" and predict "banana" if it has encountered this sequence before or something close to it. I don't think it could infer that a fruit fly is a type of insect unless you trained it on that sequence. Thus the T for Temporal. HTMs are sequence association compressors and retrievers (a form of memory). To get the pattern out of the HTM you play in a sequence and it will match the strongest representation it has encountered to date and predict the next bits of the sequence. It seems to be very good at this and the main application for HTMs right now are predicting sequences and anomalies out of streams of data.

To get more complex representations and more abstraction you would cascade a trained HTMs outputs to another HTMs inputs along with some other new sequence based input to correlate to. I suppose you could wire in some feedback and do some other tricks to combine multiple HTMs, but you would need lots of training on primitives first, just like a baby does, before you will ever get something as sophisticated as associating concepts based on syntax of the written word.

Answer (score -2):

ok guys, dont get silly, htms just copy data into them, if you want a concept, its going to be a group of the data, and then you can have motor depend on the relation, and then it all works.

our cortex, is probably way better, and actually generates new images, but a computer cortex WONT, but as it happens, it doesnt matter, and its very very useful already.

but drawing concepts from a data pool, is tricky, the easiest way to do it is by recording an invarient combination of its senses, and when it comes up, associate everything else to it, this will give you organism or animal like intelligence.

drawing harder relations, is what humans do, and its ad hoc logic, imagine a set explaining the most ad hoc relation, and then it slowly gets more and more specific, until it gets to exact motor programs... and all knowledge you have is controlling your motor, and making relations that trigger pathways in the cortex, and tell it where to go, from the blast search that checks all motor, and finds the most successful trigger.

woah that was a mouthful, but watch out dummies, you wont get no concepts from a predictive assimilator, which is what htm is, unless you work out how people draw relations in the data pool, like a machine, and if you do that, its like a program thats programming itself.

no shit.